# Strip Phone Number Input Before Validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to setup a contact_phone column in my Client model as an integer data type. I would still like to be able to allow users to enter phone numbers in whatever format they like (i.e. 999-999-9999 or 999.999.9999) and just strip out any non-numeric characters before validating it as a valid phone number.

Unfortunately, Rails doesn't seem to want to allow me to run a gsub on the data before validation because it's a FixNum datatype. Does this mean that I have to make it a string in the database to allow users to input non-numeric characters before validation?

My Client Model:

```
  before_validation :strip_contact_phone

  protected  

  def strip_contact_phone
    self.contact_phone = self.contact_phone.gsub(/[^0-9]/, '') 
  end
```

And the resulting error when trying to save a new client:

```
undefined method `gsub' for 646:Fixnum
```

Comment: that method is expecting that the object gets assigned a string and that before you save to the db it will be converted.  Your approach is fine but without knowing where it got 646 from we can't really help you as you're expecting that to be a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an integer column type is problematic because Rails performs type casting on assignment (and retrieval from) database-backed attributes. This means that, when you try to assign a string to an integer field, you'll typecast the string and lose the data. For example:

```
"123-123-1234".to_i # => 123
```

So that's why you have `undefined method 'gsub' for 646:Fixnum`. Rails has already typecast the phone number string entered by the user, truncated the value to 646, and, yes, `gsub` is not a valid method for Fixnum. So definitely change the phone number column type to String. Then you'll be free to perform your gsub and the phone number won't be truncated beforehand.

```
def strip_contact_phone
  self.contact_phone.gsub!(/[^0-9]/, '')
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Not ideal to be saving integers as a string type, but it seems to be the only way to enable me to take in strings from the user and modify them before saving. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think a phone number *should* be an Integer anyway. It's not like you do calculations with it. It's a static thing.

Comment: Phone numbers should never be saved as integers. The biggest reason is because they can start with a 0, which will be truncated if you try to save it as an integer. Phone numbers should always be saved as a string